# Android service getting destroyed in sticky mode

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

Following is my android which is started when a activity button is pressed. But i see that when the activity is killed the service is destroyed. I want the service to be alive all the time even if the app is closed/killed/cleared.

```
public class ScreenService extends Service{

    private BroadcastReceiver sReceiver;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg){
        Log.d(Constant.APP_TAG,"onBind service method called");
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startIs){
        Log.d(Constant.APP_TAG,"onStartCommand service method called");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.d(Constant.APP_TAG,"onDestroy service method called");
    }
}
```

It is started from a activity using following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenService.class);
MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
```

If i click on clear all in android i see that ondestroy method is getting called. How can i keep the service running all time or atleast ensure that it will be restarted

Comment: `START_STICKY` does not prevent a process from being terminated. It simply asks for Android to restart the service in a timely fashion afterwards. You will need your service to be a foreground service on Android 8.0+ for it to live for more than a minute, so you might consider adding that as your next step.

Comment: I am fine with android restarting my service after some time, but is it guranteed that it will be restarted at some point of time? When will that happen? and will it happen at all?

Comment: "is it guranteed that it will be restarted at some point of time?" -- very little is guaranteed. It is likely to happen. "When will that happen?" -- when the OS decides. You do not have control over that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a foreground service.

To start it, use

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, ScreenService.class));
```

In your `onCreate()` method in your Service, you'll need to then tell the service to start in the foreground:

```
@Override
public int onCreate() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel("some_id", "My Notification Channel"), Notification.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "some_id")
            .setContentTitle("My Notification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    startForeground(100, builder.build());
}
```

And in `onDestroy()`, call

```
stopForeground(true);
```